# Calculation of next week number (constrained by max 3) with rollover

Tags: java

What I want my code to do is that if we're on day 3 then we want to increase the week by 1. But if week number is 3 we want to reset the week to 1. The code below works but can it be simplified?

Java code

```
public int calculateNextWeek(int week, int day) {
    if (day == 3) {
        if (week == 3) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return week + 1;
        }
    }

    return week;
}
```

Example data and expected output:

```
day = 3, week = 1 => 2
day = 3, week = 3 => 1
day = 1, week = 1 => 1
day = 1, week = 3 => 3
```

Comment: Should be posted on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). CodeReview is for improving working code, not fixing broken code.

Comment: It is unclear if 1) your code is working as you expect it to; 2) which version/language you want reviewed.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Code is working as expected. Just looking for improvements if the logic can be simplified, for example maybe with modulo. Edited post to make it more clear that it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the modulo operator to wrap around your `week` counter:

```
public int calculateNextWeek(int week, int day) {
    if (day == 3) {
        return (week % 3) + 1;
    }

    return week;
}
```